# google app engine app.yaml for php static files don't load

Tags: php, angularjs, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am very new to GAE, I can run the app locally fine, but when running on GAE browse, it complains about script.js line 1 "Unexpected token <"

Here is the app.yaml

```
application: randomappname
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Files are referenced in the head tag

```
  <head>    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />
    <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Files located like this:

```
index.php
api.php
app.yaml
/static/main.css
/static/script.js
```

***Edit:***

I updated the app.yaml to this:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catchall `- url: /.*` should go last.  It is catching all requests. The unexpected `<` is the first character in index.php, which is the response you are getting when you request script.js.

Next, we can clean up your static file config

Comment: Thanks, I updated the app.yaml please see edit in my original post. It can now find the js but cannot find css (which I am not so concerned). however, it doesn't seem to be able to locate the api.php.

Comment: Your app.yaml is correct.  How are you calling `/api.php`?

Comment: found out the api.php is being called, the php calls a third party HTTP GET api which returns null. however it works locally. So I think GAE is blocking the HTTP GET call for some reason.

Comment: The `$` means "this is the end of the url".  Your query string makes that regex not a match.  Try: `- url: /(.+\.php)(\?*)` or `- url: /(.+\.php)(.*)`

Comment: thanks. I changed it to - url: /(.+\.php)(.*) the result is the same. I  can see the api.php is being called and parameters got passed in. I am calling a eBay api inside the api.php, it returned null as if the call didn't go through. I should make a different post about it. As for this question regarding app.yaml, you have helped me resolved it and thanks again.